# Editing an XML document on the server side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

REVISED QUESTION:

have an xml document, i wish to change the qty of a book in the xml to increment by 1 on command. is there anyway of updating an XML document through the web.

Many Thanks

Comment: It can only be submit to the server given it provides the facilities to do so. If there is an API available for the server application, you should begin investigating there. You should revise your question to make it a bit more clear, as your intent is somewhat vague.

Comment: just edited it now, hope this helps

Comment: Is this your server or only a file that exist on someone else server?

Comment: it is on my server and my website :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) editor, to edit your file and you need to implement saving in php on server side. You can post the content using jquery

```
$.post('your_script.php', {file: myCodeMirror.getValue()}, function() {
   // your file was save
});
```

and in php

```
if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
  $f = fopen('your.xml', 'w')
  fwrite($f, $_POST['file']);
  fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: isset($_POST['file'])

what does this part check for?

Comment: it check if POST is set (script is called via post and not directly typing url in address bar) and check if file post variable is set. So the code will be executed only when you call it from that javascript code above (or post a form with file input).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i was getting at:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php

the save method allows you to save it to the webserver, i will use php to open it and then save and close it with this

Comment: This is DOM in php, on server side not in javascript.

Comment: @jcubic whats wrong with that? if it updates the copy on the server thats all that matters?!

Comment: You can't call that function from javascript. You will need to exectue it from server. And you put javascript tag, so I assume that you want to edit that xml from client not server.